# How do I show a confirmation box before deleting a record

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to show a confirm box before performing this ajax request.

```
$(document).on("click", ".deletecustomer", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "deletecustomer.php",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data == "success") {
                window.location.href = "customer.php";
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { /* Ajax */ }`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".deletecustomer", function() {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            method: "post",
            url: "deletecustomer.php",
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data == "success") {
                    window.location.href = "customer.php";
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Great, if it answered your question could you go ahead and mark this answer as complete?